# Ant task to update xml file when having list of tags

Tags: ant, target, maven-ant-tasks

I have an XML file with a set of context parameters.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   version="3.1">      
    <context-param>
        <param-name>deployment.type</param-name>
        <param-value>main</param-value>
    </context-param>        
    <context-param>
        <param-name>csrf.protection.active</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>           
</web-app>
```

I want to update the param-value of 
**csrf.protection.active**

I found this ant target.

```
<target name="update-csrf-value">
    <xmltask source="${dist.dir}/docker/WEB-INF/web.xml" dest="${dist.dir}/docker/WEB-INF/web.xml" report="true">
        <replace path="/:web-app/:context-param/:param-value/text()" withText="new text"/>
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

But with this, all my parameter values get changed. How can I change the value of a specific key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. I replaced the whole tag by finding it with regex.

```
  <target name="update-csrf-value">
    <replaceregexp file="${dist.dir}/docker/WEB-INF/web.xml"
            match="&lt;param-name&gt;csrf.protection.active&lt;/param-name&gt;${line.separator}(\s*)&lt;param-value&gt;([a-z]+)&lt;/param-value&gt;"
            replace="&lt;param-name&gt;csrf.protection.active&lt;/param-name&gt;${line.separator}\1&lt;param-value&gt;false&lt;/param-value&gt;"/>
   </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to try to parse/edit XML with regex. All you have to do is fix your XPath. The following code will only modify `param-value` nodes that have sibling `param-name` nodes containing the text "deployment.type":

```
    <xmltask source="web.xml" dest="web2.xml" report="true">
        <replace path="/:web-app/:context-param/:param-name[text() = 'deployment.type']/../:param-value/text()" withText="new text"/>
    </xmltask>
```